# How to query an array inside an object inside an array?

Tags: mongodb, search, mongodb-query

Using the 3 documents as an example:

```
{ _id: '/players/b/berrijo01.shtml',
  url: '/players/b/berrijo01.shtml',
  name: 'Jose Berrios',
  image: 'https://www.baseball-reference.com/req/202108020/images/headshots/d/d94db113_mlbam.jpg',
  teams: 
   [ { name: 'MIN', years: [ 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021 ] },
     { name: 'TOR', years: [ 2021 ] } ] }
{ _id: '/players/c/cruzne02.shtml',
  url: '/players/c/cruzne02.shtml',
  name: 'Nelson Cruz',
  image: 'https://www.baseball-reference.com/req/202108020/images/headshots/f/fea2f131_mlbam.jpg',
  teams: 
   [ { name: 'MIL', years: [ 2005 ] },
     { name: 'TEX',
       years: [ 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013 ] },
     { name: 'BAL', years: [ 2014 ] },
     { name: 'SEA', years: [ 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018 ] },
     { name: 'MIN', years: [ 2019, 2020, 2021 ] },
     { name: 'TBR', years: [ 2021 ] } ] }
{ _id: '/players/m/mauerjo01.shtml',
  url: '/players/m/mauerjo01.shtml',
  name: 'Joe Mauer',
  image: 'https://www.baseball-reference.com/req/202108020/images/headshots/4/43c69595_mlbam.jpg',
  teams: 
   [ { name: 'MIN',
       years: 
        [ 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007,
          2008, 2009, 2010, 2011,
          2012, 2013, 2014, 2015,
          2016, 2017, 2018 ] } ] 
}
```

I want to get any document that has the specified year within the teams array inside the years value.

So for example if I query 2021 I would get the first and second documents. If I query for 2006 I get the second and third documents. I'm not sure how to go about this query as I'm fairly new to mongo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its very simple and you can find details here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/ , use below filter:

```
db.collection.find({
  "teams.years": 2021
})
```

and

```
db.collection.find({
  "teams.years": 2006
})
```

pls refer here https://mongoplayground.net/p/S87eJKZCjwd